# ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 8 in length when input utf-8 in python 3.6

Tags: python, utf-8, des

```
def get_encrypt_param(params):
    _salt = b"\xA9\x9B\xC8\x32\x56\x35\xE3\x03"
    _iterations = 2
    data = []
    for i in params:
        data.append("{}={}".format(i, params[i]))
    str_param = "&".join(data)
    print(str_param)
    padding = 8 - len(str_param) % 8
    str_param += chr(padding) * padding
    print(str_param)
    hasher = MD5.new()
    hasher.update(apikey.encode())
    hasher.update(_salt)
    result = hasher.digest()
    for i in range(1, _iterations):
        hasher = MD5.new()
        hasher.update(result)
        result = hasher.digest()
    encoder = DES.new(result[:8], DES.MODE_CBC, result[8:16])

    encrypted = encoder.encrypt(str_param)
    encryptParam = base64.b64encode(encrypted)
    return res
```

When I input chinese character,

```
params = {
    "name": u"张三",
    "idCard": "123456199001011233",
    "mobile": "13800138000"
}
print(get_encrypt_param(params))
```

ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 8 in length.
But it' ok when I input english character.
Please help me.
I try to :

```
for i in params:
    data.append("{}={}".format(i, params[i].encode("utf-8")))
```

But the str_param is :

```
mobile=b'13800138000'&name=b'\xe5\xbc\xa0\xe4\xb8\x89'&cardno=b'123456199001011233'
```

it's bytes and others can't recognise the decrypt params.

Answer (score 0):

use another package：pyDes

Code：

```
import pyDes


def get_encrypt_param(params):
    """对参数进行加密封装"""
    _salt = b"\xA9\x9B\xC8\x32\x56\x35\xE3\x03"
    _iterations = 2
    data = []
    for i in params:
        data.append("{}={}".format(i, params[i]))
    str_param = "&".join(data)

    hasher = MD5.new()
    hasher.update(apikey.encode())
    hasher.update(_salt)
    result = hasher.digest()
    for i in range(1, _iterations):
        hasher = MD5.new()
        hasher.update(result)
        result = hasher.digest()

    despy = pyDes.des(result[:8], pyDes.CBC, padmode=pyDes.PAD_PKCS5, IV=result[8:16])
    encrypt_data = despy.encrypt(str_param.encode())
    return base64.b64encode(encrypt_data）
```

so you can encrypt chinese character without encoding("utf-8).